# How do you log a version number using EJB stateless annotation?

Tags: java, logging, annotations, ejb

We want to log an EJB version number in a method called by EJB stateless annotation.

Using WebSphere 8.5.5 and logger.info()

Tried BeforeCompletion, Init, AfterCompletion. Nothing works.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Please, add more details to what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: Also, EJB stateless annotation does not call anything, it defines bean type.

Comment: Thank you @ Chemykh Alexander for responding. I want to do something like: @BeforeCompletion
    public void logVersion()
    {
     logger.info("EBJ MyBean version: 1.1.0");
    }

Answer (score 0):

How about using @PostConstruct interceptor? PostConstruct methods are invoked on the newly constructed instance, after any dependency injection has been performed by the container and before the first business method is invoked on the bean.

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean {

      ...

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
            System.out.println("StatelessBean version: " + getVersion());
      }

}
```